# Replacing UITabBar with UIToolbar programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I'm trying to write a tabbed application where each tab is a Navigation Controller. This tab bar appears at every view in the navigation controller as its being inferred on each view.

I would like to replace this tab bar on a detail view with a tool bar with a couple of buttons on it.

I've tried the following code in that detail view's viewDidLoad: method

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

UIBarButtonItem *accept = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Accept"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *decline = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Decline"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                               action:nil];
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:accept, decline, nil];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];

// code suggested
[self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

It still doesn't show up. Though hides the tab bar now for adding the following line in the view that's presenting the detail view:-

```
theDetailTableViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually put toolbarHidden = YES or NO, as applicable, in the viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear methods. I am not sure if that is why it is not working for you, but you need to address when you return to the presenting view anyway.

If you don't address it, the toolbar will still be visible when you go back.

Comment: Cheers pal. That worked. I used viewDidAppear to display the toolbar once view has appeared. And then I used viewWillDisappear to hide it as it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are pushing your detailViewController from, do this to hide the Tab Bar in the detail view:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController detailViewController animated:YES];
```

and in your detail view, just add the ToolBar as a subview to the detailView.

Comment: Thanks for your help @calvinBhai I've updated my question with what you've suggested. Tab bar has disappeared but the tool bar still doesn't show up.